# Reading multiple log files from a folder using python

Tags: python

In the past I have read a log file using python with the following code, which has always worked fine:

```
with open(r"24T23.log") as f, open('logfile.csv', 'w') as f2:
    writer = csv.writer(f2)
    writer.writerow(['Index','Date', 'Time', 'Logic', '(Logic)','Type', 'Code','Connector', 'Message', 'Extra 1', 'Extra 2'])

    i = 0
    for line in f:
        writer.writerow([i] + line.rstrip().split('\t'))
        i += 1
```

For a particular use case that I am working on, I need to read multiple files contained in a folder. Can someone please suggest how to modify the above code (I tried that using blob but could not succeed)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about using os module? You can use os.listdir() function to iterate through a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this?

```py
import csv
import os

# From root of cwd
DIRECTORY = 'test'

# This gets the path of every file in DIRECTORY if it is a log file
# os.path.join(os.getcwd(),x) to include cwd in directory name
logs = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), x) for x in os.listdir(
    DIRECTORY) if os.path.splitext(x)[1] == '.log']

for log in logs:
    # Note the 'a' append write, to append the rows to the files
    with open(log) as f, open('logfile.csv', 'a') as f2:
        writer = csv.writer(f2)
        writer.writerow(['Index', 'Date', 'Time', 'Logic', '(Logic)',
                        'Type', 'Code', 'Connector', 'Message', 'Extra 1', 'Extra 2'])

        i = 0
        for line in f:
            writer.writerow([i] + line.rstrip().split('\t'))
            i += 1
```

> [Docs on `os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)

Comment: while using the above code I realized that the time in the log files i.e 23:00:00:470 is read as 00:00.5. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps you should open another question? Just to be able to give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and plenty of details.

Comment: Did that here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71738174/time-not-read-correctly-while-reading-from-log-files    - @Freddy Mcloughlan